# Attaching ancestor attributes to child nodes

Tags: xslt

So I have this quite complex data that I am trying to extract a small portion out to a csv file

A heavily edited version is below

```
<Chemical id="000036884" displayFormula="UNKNOWN" displayName="Carotene">
 <NameList>
  <SystematicName>
   Carotenes and Carotenoids
   <SourceList>
    <Source>MESH</Source>
   </SourceList>
  </SystematicName>
  <Synonyms>
   Phytoxanthins
   <SourceList>
    <Source>NLM</Source>
   </SourceList>
  </Synonyms>
  <DescriptorName>Carotene</DescriptorName>
 </NameList>
</Chemical>
 <Chemical id="000050011" displayFormula="C-H5-N3.Cl-H" displayName="Guanidine, monohydrochloride">
    <NameList>
      <Synonyms>
        AI3-19014
        <SourceList>
          <Source>NLM</Source>
        </SourceList>
      </Synonyms>
</Chemical>
```

NOTE - sometimes there is no SystematicName or no Synonyms or neither
What I am trying to get out is

```
"000036884","Carotene"
"000036884","Carotenes and Carotenoids"
"000036884","Phytoxanthins"
```

At the moment I can only work out how to drop the id and the displayName in this format, but can't work out how to extract the id with every line..

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <xsl:variable name="FS">
    <!-- Field seperator -->
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="LT">
    <!-- Line terminator -->
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//Chemical[@displayName != '' and @displayName != 'INDEX NAME NOT YET ASSIGNED']">
        <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="@displayName" />
      <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>&#44;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/sid/startswith/<xsl:value-of select="@id" />
      <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>&#44;&#34;nlm&#34;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="$LT" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This XSLT can only give me

```
"000036884","Carotene","nlm"
```

I am looking for help to create XSLT for the desired output (first sample output)

Working solution is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <xsl:variable name="FS">
    <!-- Field seperator -->
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="LT">
    <!-- Line terminator -->
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//Chemical[@displayName != '' and @displayName != 'INDEX NAME NOT YET ASSIGNED']">
        <xsl:call-template name="printValues">
            <xsl:with-param name="val1" select="@id" />
            <xsl:with-param name="val2" select="@displayName" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(NameList/SystematicName/text()) != ''">
        <xsl:call-template name="printValues">
            <xsl:with-param name="val1" select="@id" />
            <xsl:with-param name="val2" select="normalize-space(NameList/SystematicName/text())" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(NameList/Synonyms/text()) != ''">
        <xsl:call-template name="printValues">
            <xsl:with-param name="val1" select="@id" />
            <xsl:with-param name="val2" select="normalize-space(NameList/Synonyms/text())" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="printValues">
    <xsl:param name="val1" />
    <xsl:param name="val2" />
    <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$val2" />
    <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#44;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/sid/startswith/<xsl:value-of select="$val1" /><xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#44;&#34;nlm&#34;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The XSLT shared does not seem to match the shared output as there is no XSLT code that outputs `Phytoxanthins`. Could you please share the correct XSLT?

Comment: If I had the correct XSLT, I wouldn't be asking how to get the output I want would I? :) Updated question to explain this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the desired output, you can create a template that uses 2 params in the input and prints the data in the required structure/format.

```
<xsl:template name="printValues">
    <xsl:param name="val1" />
    <xsl:param name="val2" />

    <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$val1" />
    <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>

    <xsl:text>&#44;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$val2" />
    <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

This template can be called from the `<xsl:for-each>` loop using the values that need to printed.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//Chemical[@displayName != '' and @displayName != 'INDEX NAME NOT YET ASSIGNED']">
        <xsl:call-template name="printValues">
            <xsl:with-param name="val1" select="@id" />
            <xsl:with-param name="val2" select="@displayName" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="printValues">
            <xsl:with-param name="val1" select="@id" />
            <xsl:with-param name="val2" select="normalize-space(NameList/SystematicName/text())" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="printValues">
            <xsl:with-param name="val1" select="@id" />
            <xsl:with-param name="val2" select="normalize-space(NameList/Synonyms/text())" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This will give the desired output.

```
"000036884","Carotene"
"000036884","Carotenes and Carotenoids"
"000036884","Phytoxanthins"
```

Comment: it works, though on a libxml based processor it fails due to a too big an XPATH, using up the memory... trying it on under xalan..

Comment: OK it worked on xalan... however - sometimes the Chemical doesn't have a Synonym  - how would I detect and skip those? at the moment I get an ""

Comment: Ideally this should have been a separate question according to SO guidelines. To skip the empty values, you can add an `<xsl:if>` condition in the `<xsl:for-each>` loop to call the `printValues` template only for non-empty values or you can add the `<xsl:if>` condition inside the `printValues` template to print only when `$val2` is non-empty.

Comment: Well its not so much that they are empty as they don't exist sometimes there is no SystematicName or no Synonyms or neither. So would it be <xsl:if normalize-space(NameList/SystematicName/text()) != ''> <xsl:call-template name="printValues">.... ?

Comment: Please provide input data such that it satisfies all the requirements and also add the corresponding output so that the given solution would be complete.