# Attaching parent attributes to child nodes with multiple children

Tags: xslt

this is linked from [Attaching ancestor attributes to child nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47176687/attaching-ancestor-attributes-to-child-nodes/47179218)

I'm extracting names from a large xml dataset, I need to extract displayname, and the other name types (currently I am only picking out Synonyms and SystematicNames). Right now with the help of an awesome person I've gotten so far, but it only extracts the first of each type...

Sample XML

```
  <Chemical id="0000103902" displayFormula="C8-H9-N-O2" displayName="Acetaminophen [USP:JAN]">
    <NameList>
      <DescriptorName>Acetaminophen<SourceList><Source>MeSH</Source></SourceList></DescriptorName>
      <NameOfSubstance>Acetaminophen<SourceList><Source>HSDB</Source><Source>MeSH</Source></SourceList></NameOfSubstance>
      <NameOfSubstance>Acetaminophen [USP:JAN]<SourceList><Source>NLM</Source></SourceList></NameOfSubstance>
      <MixtureName>Actifed Plus<SourceList><Source>MeSH</Source></SourceList></MixtureName>
      <MixtureName>Jin Gang<SourceList><Source>NLM</Source></SourceList></MixtureName>
      <MixtureName>Talacen<SourceList><Source>NLM</Source></SourceList></MixtureName>
      <SystematicName>Acetamide, N-(4-hydroxyphenyl)-<SourceList><Source>EPA SRS</Source><Source>MeSH</Source><Source>TSCAINV</Source></SourceList></SystematicName>
      <SystematicName>Acetaminophen<SourceList><Source>CCRIS</Source></SourceList></SystematicName>
      <SystematicName>Acetanilide, 4'-hydroxy-<SourceList><Source>RTECS</Source></SourceList></SystematicName>
      <SystematicName>Paracetamol<SourceList><Source>ECHA</Source><Source>EINECS</Source></SourceList></SystematicName>
      <Synonyms>4-13-00-01091 (Beilstein Handbook Reference)<SourceList><Source>RTECS</Source></SourceList></Synonyms>
      <Synonyms>Abensanil<SourceList><Source>HSDB</Source><Source>RTECS</Source></SourceList></Synonyms>
      <Synonyms>Acetagesic<SourceList><Source>HSDB</Source><Source>RTECS</Source></SourceList></Synonyms>
      <Synonyms>Acetamide, N-(p-hydroxyphenyl)-<SourceList><Source>RTECS</Source></SourceList></Synonyms>
    </NameList>
  </Chemical>
```

Current code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <xsl:variable name="FS">
    <!-- Field seperator -->
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="LT">
    <!-- Line terminator -->
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//Chemical[@displayName != '' and @displayName != 'INDEX NAME NOT YET ASSIGNED']">
        <xsl:call-template name="printValues">
            <xsl:with-param name="val1" select="@id" />
            <xsl:with-param name="val2" select="@displayName" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(NameList/SystematicName/text()) != ''">
        <xsl:call-template name="printValues">
            <xsl:with-param name="val1" select="@id" />
            <xsl:with-param name="val2" select="normalize-space(NameList/SystematicName/text())" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(NameList/Synonyms/text()) != ''">
        <xsl:call-template name="printValues">
            <xsl:with-param name="val1" select="@id" />
            <xsl:with-param name="val2" select="normalize-space(NameList/Synonyms/text())" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="printValues">
    <xsl:param name="val1" />
    <xsl:param name="val2" />

    <!-- constants -->
    <xsl:variable name="url" select="'https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/sid/startswith/'" />
    <xsl:variable name="src" select="'nlm'" />

    <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="escapeQuote">
        <xsl:with-param name="paramStr" select="$val2" />
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>

    <xsl:text>&#44;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($url, $val1)" />
    <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>

    <xsl:text>&#44;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$src" />
    <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="escapeQuote">
    <xsl:param name="paramStr" />

    <xsl:if test="string-length($paramStr) > 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($paramStr, '&quot;'), '&quot;')" />
        <xsl:if test="contains($paramStr, '&quot;')">
            <xsl:text>\"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="escapeQuote">
                <xsl:with-param name="paramStr" select="substring-after($paramStr, '&quot;')" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However this only gives:-

```
"Acetaminophen [USP:JAN]","https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/sid/startswith/0000103902","nlm"
"Acetamide, N-(4-hydroxyphenyl)-","https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/sid/startswith/0000103902","nlm"
"4-13-00-01091 (Beilstein Handbook Reference)","https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/sid/startswith/0000103902","nlm"
```

How do I go about extracting all the children in the same manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printing of the text values in the `<SystematicName>` and `<Synonyms>` nodes can be achieved by adding `<xsl:for-each>` loop for those elements. The `<xsl:if>` condition can also be handled in the `<xsl:for-each>` selection.

Please modify the `<xsl:template match="/">` as shown below.

```
<xsl:template match="Chemical[@displayName != '' and @displayName != 'INDEX NAME NOT YET ASSIGNED']">
    <xsl:variable name="idValue" select="@id" />
    <xsl:call-template name="printValues">
        <xsl:with-param name="val1" select="$idValue" />
        <xsl:with-param name="val2" select="@displayName" />
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:for-each select="NameList/SystematicName[text() != '']">
        <xsl:call-template name="printValues">
            <xsl:with-param name="val1" select="$idValue" />
            <xsl:with-param name="val2" select="normalize-space(text())" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select="NameList/Synonyms[text() != '']">
        <xsl:call-template name="printValues">
            <xsl:with-param name="val1" select="$idValue" />
            <xsl:with-param name="val2" select="normalize-space(text())" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Output

```
"Acetaminophen [USP:JAN]","https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/sid/startswith/0000103902","nlm"
"Acetamide, N-(4-hydroxyphenyl)-","https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/sid/startswith/0000103902","nlm"
"Acetaminophen","https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/sid/startswith/0000103902","nlm"
"Acetanilide, 4'-hydroxy-","https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/sid/startswith/0000103902","nlm"
"Paracetamol","https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/sid/startswith/0000103902","nlm"
"4-13-00-01091 (Beilstein Handbook Reference)","https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/sid/startswith/0000103902","nlm"
"Abensanil","https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/sid/startswith/0000103902","nlm"
"Acetagesic","https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/sid/startswith/0000103902","nlm"
"Acetamide, N-(p-hydroxyphenyl)-","https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/sid/startswith/0000103902","nlm"
```